# How to install VideoLAN Movie Creator?

Tags: 14.04, video-editor

I'd like to get [VideoLAN Movie Creator](http://www.videolan.org/vlmc/) for my Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any possibility? Or any other similar to Windows Movie Maker? Openshot is very weak and all the others from software center even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Webupd8.org [maintains](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/vlmc) a VLMC PPA [since 2010](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/videolan-movie-creator-vlmc-daily-ppa.html). Have you tried that? The latest upload was in January 2015, so it's missing packages for Vivid and Wily, but 14.04 is covered.

Related:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/40581)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/40581)